# Under what conditions do stores replenish?

Tags: fallout-4

I sold out a store's money/cap supply and sitting on a couch for 24 hours didn't do anything. What do I need to do to make the store replenish its money/wares/supplies? Does everything refresh at once? What are the refresh conditions?

Comment: I've had stores refill their stocks after waiting for the next day a few times. Which store was it, and did you wait in the same area as the store, or elsewhere?

Answer (score 1):

Just wait around 3-4 days in-game and it should restock.